# Quickly detect if VM is running on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, metadata

One way of detecting if a VM (in my case a Docker container running on a Linux VM) is running on Azure is to query the metadata service for some information using HTTP.

This trick works nicely on AWS and GCP where the query can be done using DNS names (`instance-data.ec2.internal` and `metadata.google.internal`) and thus the query will fail quickly when the DNS lookup is being done.

But for Azure I do not know of any DNS name for the metadata service, only its raw IP address (`169.254.169.254`) and the code has to wait for the request to time out instead which take much longer time.

One solution to this would be to find a DNS name for the Azure Metadata Service, but there might be other solutions to the problem as well.

Comment: The other solution would be for you to time-bound your external calls (e.g. fail the call if it takes over 4 seconds).

Comment: @evilSnobu Correct, I have been thinking of doing that, but it would be nice to find a way of knowing that could be done in milliseconds. Thanks!

Comment: Check your `/etc/resolv.conf`. There's an Azure specific domain part you can query for.

Answer (score 0):

"Check your /etc/resolv.conf. There's an Azure specific domain part you can query for."

The domain I found was: cloudapp.net

Check the domain you find against this list:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/azure-domains

Thanks to @evilSnobu.